# Access host nearest you

Tags: asp.net, iis

I currently have a web application Asp.Net MVC that is hosted in Europe. Problem is that this application is used by people both in the US and in China and the ones in china are experiencing the site very slow. I dont think that their internet connection is slow but the response time for the application is about 400 - 500 ms

Is it possible to host Asp.Net webapplication on two hosts and when you access the application  you access the host nearest you?

Comment: Well a fast and dirty solution, is to have two servers, two url names, one ending on ".com" and one ending on ".jp" for example, and the one is near china, the other is near europe. And also if use from china come to ".com" you can recognize that from their ip, and redirect him on the other site.